# Garry's Mod custom spectate player

Tags: game, lua

I have been making my own scoreboard, and needed a custom spectate function for it, so I made this:

```
  util.AddNetworkString( "spectatePlayer" )
  local playerLocal
  local isSpectating = false

 net.Receive("spectatePlayer", function(length, client)
    if isSpectating then return end
        isSpectating = true
        playerLocal = client
        print(client:Nick() .. "Started spectating: " .. net.ReadEntity():Nick())
        client:Spectate(5)
        client:SpectateEntity(net.ReadEntity())

 end)

 hook.Add("Tick", "keydown", function()
        if not isSpectating then return end
                if (playerLocal:KeyDown(IN_FORWARD)) then
                        isSpectating = false
                        playerLocal:UnSpectate()
                        print(playerLocal:Nick().."Finished Spectating")
                end
        end)
```

Is there anything I could improve on? Am I over-complicating anything?

Comment: Please add in what the custom behavior is -- just saying that it's custom isn't very specific.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things to comment on:

---

I'm not a Gmod developer, so I'm not familiar with the spectating abilities built in, but, I'd assume that if any exist, they're probably better to use than re-inventing the wheel.

---

There's only two states: not spectating, and spectating. What happens if I want to simply switch between players? Do I have to stop spectating, and then select a new player to spectate?

Why can I not just press <kbd>lmb</kbd> and go to the next?

---

> ```
> util.AddNetworkString( "spectatePlayer" )
> ```

You've got extraneous whitespace in your brackets.

---

> ```
> print(client:Nick() .. "Started spectating: " .. net.ReadEntity():Nick())
> print(playerLocal:Nick().."Finished Spectating")
> ```

String concatenation joins the strings, as they are. Meaning, it would read like:

> QuillStarted spectating: James Heald.
>   QuillFinished Spectating

Add some whitespace in there.

```
print(client:Nick() .. " Started spectating: " .. net.ReadEntity():Nick())
print(playerLocal:Nick().." Finished Spectating")
```

---

Oh, and you should be keeping the cases (upper and lower) consistent in your messages:

> ```
> "Started spectating: "
>          ^
> "Finished Spectating"
>           ^
> ```